# Storing Private Key Files on Android 10 as a User

Tags: encryption, password-management, android, ssh

Say I have a private key as a user of an existing application for SSH, password management, etc.

As far as I know if it is in shared storage, any application with storage permissions can access it.

If the application that requires such a key doesn't save it to it's application storage, is there any way to securely store something like that on Android 10 as a user?

Comment: There are encrypted storage apps.

Comment: Can you recommend any FOSS ones?

Comment: Product recommendations are out-of-scope here.

Comment: Use [hardware backed keystore](https://source.android.com/security/keystore).

Comment: @defalt I believe the OP wants to store the key for later extraction. The KeyStore will not allow extraction of the key.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 Keystore will encrypt the private key which can be decrypted by it whenever required.

Comment: @defalt Oh ok. I was thinking you were talking about importing the key into the KeyStore. Encrypting it makes more sense.